# Applying Permission Scope on Relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, rolify

Let's say that I'm using the [`rolify`](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem.  The rolify gem handles permissions that a user can have on resource instances or a resource class.  This is simple.  If one needed to find out if a user could perform a certain task, it would result in something similar to this:

```
if user.has_role? :admin
  @article.update(article_params)
else
  fail # just as an example
end
```

However, I want to be able to apply these permissions on a scope, e.g. `Article.all` - specifically, I want to be able to determine which articles that a user can read.  Assuming that only users with the role `:admin` can read articles, how would I go about doing this?

Edit: The problem I'm facing is this.  I don't know, at runtime, which articles that any given user would be able to read.  That information is stored in the database.  Therefore, using a solution like cancancan or pundit would not - and cannot - help in this instance *(note: I actually do use pundit)*.  Essentially, I have to figure out how to implement the Pundit's `Scope` class.

Before I found the `rolify` gem, I posed the question to a friend as such:

> So what I did in order to solve it was this: every user has a set of groups; permissions can be defined on either the user or the groups (both work). Permissions effect a generalized set of records (where I just store the record type, with no ID), a specific record (record type and ID), or on the record as a whole (the record type, no ID, with a global flag). Permissions can also be negated, effectively removing any permissions a user has on a subject. So my database looks somewhat like this:
>
> ```
> Permissions
>    id: Integer
>    actor_id: Integer
>    actor_type: String
>    subject_id: Integer
>    subject_type: String
>    action: String
>    negated: Boolean
>    global: Boolean
>    precedence: Integer
>
> Users
>    id: Integer
>
> Groups
>    id: Integer
>
> Articles
>    id: Integer
> ```
>
> I included Articles to help demonstrate what I'm trying to do. So if I apply these permissions:
>
> ```
> Permission.create(actor: Group.find(1), subject: Article.find(1), action: "show")
> Permission.create(actor: Group.find(1), subject_type: "Article", action: "show")
> Permission.create(actor: User.find(1), subject: Article.find(1), action: "show", negated: true, precedence: 1)
> ```
>
> When I go `permission_scope(Article, User.find(1))`, I should get this:
>
> ```
> [#<Article id=2>, #<Article id=3>, ...]
> ```
>
> The problem is, I don't know what the contents of `permission_scope` would be, so I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Use an authorization system such as CanCanCan or Pundit.

Comment: @max Did you even read the question?

Comment: I agree with @max, CanCanCan does this very well

Comment: @max I apologize, it seems I didn't make myself clear in the question.  I've attempted everything I know of to solve this problem, and it's just slightly frustrating to see "just use x" even though I have, and it hasn't even come close to solving it.  When I come to Stack Overflow for help, it's because I've exhausted every other resource I have.  So again, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, i don't understand the problem on this, you say that there is some logic in the database, you just apply that logic using the scope below, it is not wildly different from how it is done in pundit if you read through the source

Comment: @Austio give me a moment to clarify what I'm attempting to do, it's difficult to explain :v

Comment: I hope that clarifies it, if it doesn't, let me know.

Comment: Hey Jeremy it definitely does, it sounds like you are wanting just a

Answer (score 1):

These are the basic policy examples from the Pundit readme adapted for Rolify.

For a simple case where you only need to check for a role on the user:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      if user.has_role?(:admin)
        scope.all
      else
        scope.where(:published => true)
      end
    end
  end

  def update?
    user.has_role?(:admin) or not post.published?
  end
end
```

If you have resource scoped roles you can use the [scopes provided by Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#6-resource-roles-querying):

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      Post.with_role(:author, user)
      # or
      Post.with_all_roles([:author, :editor], user)
    end
  end

  def update?
    user.has_role?(:author, post)
  end
end
```

### Why it's complicated:

To do the same scoping with your permissions system you would need something like:

```
user = User.joins(:permissions, groups: [:permissions]).find(1)

article_ids = Permission.where(
  actor_id: [user.id] + groups.ids,
  subject_type: 'Article',
  action: :show
).pluck(:subject_id)

Article.where(id: article_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not what I'm looking for - the permissions that each role has on each resource is determinant by records in the database, and so this can't work for my case.

Comment: Well in that case the only concrete  I have advice is either to stick with you current permissions based scheme or convert to a role based authorization system. Mixing in Rolify in a bespoke system which sounds a little heavy handed is probably not going to make things easier.

Comment: I just don't understand why this is complicated, nor why any library hasn't implemented it.  Maybe my use case is too specific to what I'm doing?

Comment: It's complicated due to the queries involved - you need need to pull users, groups and permissions out of the database and then use them to scope the query for the actual resource. This is pretty complicated for generic library which does not know the class or table for any of the models involved. The has been a long running issue to support something like this in Rolify https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/80

Comment: https://github.com/medcat/tempest/blob/master/lib/ability/policy/scope.rb This is what I have to do currently.  After a conversation with Austio, I'm going to scale back what I have to make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update you certainly want this logic in a separate class and probably in different modules due to the perceived complexity.  If this is in any open source stuff let me know because seeing it in use will help more.  This is not an easy problem but hopefully this will get you closer.

```
module Scope
  class Permission < Struct.new(:relation, :entity, :action)
    def call
      relation.merge(::Query::Permission.new(:relation, :entity, :action)
    end
  end
end

module Query
  class Permission < Struct.new(:relation, :entity, :action)
    def call 
      #Here is where you implement the logic to find records related to a relation/entity/action
    end
  end
end
```

So now you have something that takes care of scoping and something that will search through your permission stuff to find the correct records.

Comment: The problem is, the information about which articles that the user can read is stored in the database - there would be no way for me to know before hand, and create a specific scope for it.

Comment: I do use pundit, though, and I love it.  I moved from cancan/cancancan to pundit.

Comment: Ok, please specify more in your question, if it is in the database then you would apply whatever logic you want to in this scope method.

Comment: @JeremyRodi Sounds like you are just needing a query object?  Something that would do the find to produce the array that you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I believe that is the case.

Comment: Ok will do my best to update with how i would approach.  Hope it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85054/discussion-between-austio-and-jeremy-rodi).